# Bootstrap 3.3 collapse works for each same elements except first one

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on dictionary. In article edit form there are many translations of word. Also, for each translation, we can add Images and Subjects, but those div's are collapsed by default. And they expand by click, all except first one. I can't understand why first element doesn't expand. All code is the same.I tried many ways like:

- data-target vs href,
- $("elementId").collapse(),
- checked code of each same element to see difference between it...

but didn't find the solution. 
I use this plugin: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse
You can repeat my experience on the page http://dict.arabera.org/article/20463

[image]

Rendered code looks like:

```html
<div class="translations">
        
        <div class="translation" id="translation-translations.0">
          <div class="editField" id="translations.0">
    <div class="mainRow">
      
      <input type="text" name="translations.0.translation" class="form-control translation" placeholder="перевод">
      <!--
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-translation -remove" id="remove.{{item.id}}"></i>
      -->
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#subjects-translations-0" data-toggle="collapse" class="" aria-expanded="true">+ subject</a></li>
          <li><a href="#images-translations-0" data-toggle="collapse" class="" aria-expanded="true">+ image</a></li>

          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a class="remove-translation" id="remove.translations.0">- delete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subjects collapse tags" id="subjects-translations-0">
    <div class="-dropdown-container">
    <input id="tagInput" type="text" class="form-control tagInput" placeholder="+ добавить тематику">
    
  </div>
  
  </div>

  <div class="images collapse" id="images-translations-0">
    <div class="row">
    
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs add-image translation-actions" id="addImageFor.translations.0">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Картинка
  </button>
  </div>

          <div class="examples" id="examples-for-translations.0">
            
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs add-example translation-actions" id="addExampleFor.translations.0">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Пример
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="translation" id="translation-translations.1">
          <div class="editField" id="translations.1">
    <div class="mainRow">
      
      <input type="text" name="translations.1.translation" class="form-control translation" placeholder="перевод">
      <!--
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-translation -remove" id="remove.{{item.id}}"></i>
      -->
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#subjects-translations-1" data-toggle="collapse" class="" aria-expanded="true">+ subject</a></li>
          <li><a href="#images-translations-1" data-toggle="collapse" class="" aria-expanded="true">+ image</a></li>

          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a class="remove-translation" id="remove.translations.1">- delete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subjects tags collapse in" id="subjects-translations-1" aria-expanded="true" style="">
    <div class="-dropdown-container">
    <input id="tagInput" type="text" class="form-control tagInput" placeholder="+ добавить тематику">
    
  </div>
  
  </div>

  <div class="images collapse in" id="images-translations-1" aria-expanded="true" style="">
    <div class="row">
    
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs add-image translation-actions" id="addImageFor.translations.1">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Картинка
  </button>
  </div>

          <div class="examples" id="examples-for-translations.1">
            
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs add-example translation-actions" id="addExampleFor.translations.1">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Пример
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="translation" id="translation-translations.2">
          <div class="editField" id="translations.2">
    <div class="mainRow">
      
      <input type="text" name="translations.2.translation" class="form-control translation" placeholder="перевод">
      <!--
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-translation -remove" id="remove.{{item.id}}"></i>
      -->
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#subjects-translations-2" data-toggle="collapse" class="" aria-expanded="true">+ subject</a></li>
          <li><a href="#images-translations-2" data-toggle="collapse" class="" aria-expanded="true">+ image</a></li>

          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a class="remove-translation" id="remove.translations.2">- delete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subjects tags collapse in" id="subjects-translations-2" aria-expanded="true" style="">
    <div class="-dropdown-container">
    <input id="tagInput" type="text" class="form-control tagInput" placeholder="+ добавить тематику">
    
  </div>
  
  </div>

  <div class="images collapse in" id="images-translations-2" aria-expanded="true" style="">
    <div class="row">
    
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs add-image translation-actions" id="addImageFor.translations.2">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Картинка
  </button>
  </div>

          <div class="examples" id="examples-for-translations.2">
            
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs add-example translation-actions" id="addExampleFor.translations.2">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Пример
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm add-translation">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Перевод
        </button>
      </div>
```

The template, which generates the form, looks like:

```html
<template name="ArticleForm">
  <form
    id="articleForm-{{_id}}"
    class="panel panel-default article {{#if notPublished}}-opacity-06{{/if}}"
  >
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title words">
        <div class="label label-info speach-part">{{ speachPart }}</div>
        <br />
        <!--
          Глагол 1й породы имеет дополнительную информацию для вывода, поэтому
          особый шаблон его вывода, например, среднекорневую глассную и масдары
        -->
        {{#each article.words}}
        <div class="wordEdit editField" id="{{wordId}}">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-word -remove" id="remove.{{wordId}}"></i>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="прим."
            value="{{note}}"
            name="{{wordId}}.note"
            class="form-control note"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="слово"
            value="{{word}}"
            name="{{wordId}}.word"
            class="form-control word -arabic-text-mid"
          />
        </div>
        {{#if showMiddleHarakat ../speachPart @index}}
        <div class="note middleHarakat" title="среднекорневая гласная настоящего времени">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="скгнв"
            value="{{../middleHarakat}}"
            name="middleHarakat"
            class="form-control note"
          />
        </div>
        {{/if}} {{/each}}
        <div class="add-word"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="translations">
        {{#each tr in article.translations}}
        <div class="translation" id="translation-{{tr.id}}">
          {{> TranslationItem templateInstance=templateInstance item=tr}}

          <div class="examples" id="examples-for-{{tr.id}}">
            {{#each ex in tr.examples}}
            <div class="example" id="example-{{ex.id}}">
              {{> TranslationItem templateInstance=templateInstance item=ex isExample=true}}
            </div>
            {{/each}}
            <button
              class="btn btn-default btn-xs add-example translation-actions"
              id="addExampleFor.{{tr.id}}"
            >
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Пример
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm add-translation">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Перевод
        </button>
      </div>

      {{> TagsRoots}} {{> TagsMorphology parentTemplateInstance=templateInstance}}
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary article-save">Сохранить</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default article-edit-cancel">Отмена</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<template name="ImagesEdit">
  <div class="row">
    {{#each images}}
    <div class="col-sm-4 imageColumn">{{> ImageEdit}}</div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>

  <button
    class="btn btn-default btn-xs add-image translation-actions"
    id="addImageFor.{{elementId}}"
  >
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Картинка
  </button>
</template>

<template name="ImageEdit">
  <div class="thumbnail image editField" id="{{imageId}}">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-image -remove" id="remove.{{imageId}}"></i>
    <img class="form-control" placeholder="preview" src="{{image}}" />
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="ссылка на картинку"
      value="{{image}}"
      name="{{imageId}}.image"
      class="form-control imageLink"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<!-- TranslationItem means both: translation and example, which are similar -->
<template name="TranslationItem">
  <div class="editField" id="{{item.id}}">
    <div class="mainRow">
      {{#if isExample }}
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="пример"
        value="{{item.example}}"
        name="{{item.id}}.example"
        class="form-control example -arabic-text-mid"
      />
      {{/if}}
      <input
        type="text"
        name="{{item.id}}.translation"
        value="{{item.translation}}"
        class="form-control translation"
        placeholder="перевод"
      />
      <!--
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-translation -remove" id="remove.{{item.id}}"></i>
      -->
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#subjects-{{replaceDot item.id}}" data-toggle="collapse">+ subject</a></li>
          <li><a href="#images-{{replaceDot item.id}}" data-toggle="collapse">+ image</a></li>

          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a class="remove-translation" id="remove.{{item.id}}">- delete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subjects collapse tags" id="subjects-{{replaceDot item.id}}">
    {{> TagsSubjects parentTemplateInstance=templateInstance elementName=item.id}}
  </div>

  <div class="images collapse" id="images-{{replaceDot item.id}}">
    {{> ImagesEdit images=item.images elementId=item.id}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you have any additional javascript code you could share? Or are you solely relying on the javascript from the bootstrap library?

Comment: @AngelGarcia, in this case I use solely bootstrap code, which works automatically from html tags like "data-toggle", "data-target" etc. I updated article and add template of edit form. how it generates